# Probability of rounds won on average

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Alice has a probability $(p)$ of beating Bob if Alice had not won the
>   previous round, and a probability of $(q)$ if Alice had won the
>   previous round.
>
> How would you determine what percentage of games Alice wins on
>   average?

I'm really struggling with this question

$p^k$ probability of beating bob if alice had not won the previous round so where k is the round number
and $q$ if alice had won the previous round

so the average would be $p^k * q$ / $total number of games$

but this isn't right..

I dont have much insight into probability, and haven't taken statistics in a couple years. So any insight would be helpful

Comment: What are the probabilities on the first round?  Or do you want the limit for a large number of games?

Answer (score 1):

We have two states, which I'll call N (No, Alice did not win the last game) and Y (Yes, Alice won the last game.)  If we are in state N at game $n$, the probability that we remain in state N at game $n+1$ is $1-p$ and the probability that we switch to state Y is $p$.  If we are in state $Y$ at game $n$, then we remain in state Y with probability $q$, and switch states with probability $1-q.$  This is called a Markov Chain, and it turns out that there is a steady-state probability.  That is, if we call $x_n$ the probability that we are in state N after $n$ games, and $y_n$ the probability that we are in state Y, then as Alice and Bob play game, $x_n$ and $y_n$ will approach limits $x$ and $y$.

We have $$
\begin{align}
x_np+y_nq&=y_{n+1}\\
x_n+y_n&=1
\end{align}$$

Letting $n\to\infty$ we get
$$
\begin{align}
xp+yq&=y\\
x+y&=1
\end{align}$$ 
and solving gives $$
x=\frac{1-q}{1+p-q}, y=\frac{p}{1+p-q}
$$
If Alice and Bob play $n$ games, we expect them to be in state N $nx$ and in state Y $ny$ times.  Alice will win, on average, $pnx+qny$ times or $$
\frac{n}{1-p+q}(p-pq+pq)=\frac{np}{1-p+q}\text{ times}$$ so the fraction of games Alice wins is $$\boxed{\frac{p}{1-p+q}}$$

Comment: You could have stopped after solving for $y$, since the fraction of wins = the fraction of time spent happily reminiscing about having won the last game.  ;)

Comment: @antkam Good point